# Why we need serializers while we can return Response as Json without any serialzer in django rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm just confuse that while we can return json data as Response without using serialzers then why we use serializers?

Here is a simple user profile view which i am rendering without using serialzer:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def view_profile(request):
    response_data = {}

    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user
        try:
            get_user = User.objects.get(email=user.email)

            response_data['username'] = get_user.username
            response_data['email'] = get_user.email
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            response_data['response'] = str(e)

    return Response(response_data)
```

What is the main purpose of using serialzers?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* serializers for the sake of having serializers.
However, they help in several ways.

They convert complex structures -datetimes, Model instances- into more simple ones -strings, dicts, lists, integers and floats.

They also provide a structure to build schemas (OpenAPI for example) or allow the BrowsableAPI to interact with the web service through HTML forms deduced from serializers.

Comment: What if i did not use serializer and my api is working well?